# Media Player reproduce video en pantalla negra con sonido

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes, tengo un control de Windows Media Player en C# el cuál me abre el video pero no muestra imagen, aparece con imagen negra, pero puede escucharse el sonido.

En la ventana de Designer tengo lo siguiente:

```
 private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(FormVideo));
        this.wmPlayer = new AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.wmPlayer)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // wmPlayer
        // 
        this.wmPlayer.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.wmPlayer.Enabled = true;
        this.wmPlayer.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.wmPlayer.Name = "wmPlayer";
        this.wmPlayer.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("wmPlayer.OcxState")));
        this.wmPlayer.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(736, 539);
        this.wmPlayer.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // FormVideo
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.AutoSize = true;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(736, 539);
        this.Controls.Add(this.wmPlayer);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Name = "FormVideo";
        this.ShowIcon = false;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.wmPlayer)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me respondo a mi mismo, he puesto la URL directamente en las propiedades del control Media Player y ha funcionado correctamente. Nuevamente lo he quitado ya que la idea era pasar la url por un método y no sé por qué pero ahora funciona sin haber tocado nada del código.

Lo doy por solucionado entonces. Gracias